Query Store skips queries with FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION option
Using Query Store in SQL Server 2019 and noticing that queries with FORCE_LEGACY_CARDINALITY_ESTIMATION option are not showing up. Is that a known limitation of Query Store?
I tried OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 9481) instead but same results.
I modified query store capture mode to ALL
